# android phone does not vibrate

Tags: android

this is my code:

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { 
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
  Calendar ctaq = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat dfaq = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String crntdt = dfaq.format(ctaq.getTime());

  String appt ="SELECT * FROM MYDATABASE_NAME where KEY_DATE ='"+crntdt+"';";
  cursor =  mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
  String title, place;
  title = cursor.getString(1);
  place = cursor.getString(2);
  Toast.makeText(arg0, "Beellamni keessan!!"+title+" dhaqabeera !!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) arg0.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  vibrator.vibrate(2000);
 }
```

Why this is not vibrating?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the required permissions to your manifest? You should add:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @ChalaSembeta this should help you immensely, take a peak https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4rQ9S7mCdk